# GeoPandas sjoin issue that returns an empty dataframe, or a join with all nan values from the right df

Tags: python, geopandas

I've tried joining two data frames shown below (some columns missing for privacy). I'm showing the relevant geometries though. One is a multipolygon, and the other a set of coordinate points:

[image: dataframe1]

gdf2:

[image: dataframe2]

I have already confirmed that the CRS formats are correct and uniform:

```py
gdf2 = gdf2.to_crs(epsg = 4326)
gFacilities = gFacilities.to_crs(epsg = 4326)
cell = cell.to_crs(epsg = 4326)
gwsdf = gwsdf.to_crs(epsg = 4326)
```

I've also made sure there are no null or nan values in either dataframe's geometry columns. Yet, when I attempt an sjoin:

`merged = gdf2.sjoin(gwsdf, how='left', predicate='within')`

The result is a dataframe that has all nan values for the right dataframe columns, and odd resultant geometry values (result using the above sjoin parameters shown):
[image]

or an empty dataframe using the below sjoin parameters:
`merged = gdf2.sjoin(gwsdf, how='inner', predicate='within')`
[image]

Oddly enough, this sjoin process works perfectly fine with the cell dataframe instead of the gwsdf dataframe, shown above, with no nan values at all, and no empty dataframe results. The only difference that I know of is that cell's geometry is just a bunch of squares (polygons) vs the multipolygon complex shapes in gdf2.

Any insight? I'm quite new at this.

Comment: Add the code as text instead of screenshots of it. Are you trying to join polygons to points with `within` predicate? A polygon can never be within a point, try `intersection` instead

Comment: Sure I can add the code in a couple hours. Right, I’m trying to join the data frames by the points ‘within’ the polygons. Is that not how it’s being shown now?

Comment: I’ve had a quick chance to take a look before leaving the house. Switching the dataframes around results in the same exact issues. The only difference is the nan values are created on the opposite dataframe, overwriting everything.

Comment: I think you need to add some reproducable data to your question. So people can reproduce the problem.